# Execute an action in JTable before a row is selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable

everybody!

In my application I will need to create a passive JTable. By passive I mean that the selection of row is not done directly by the JTable, but when requested by another component. So, when the user go to a new row the table doesn't react immediately, but first ask a dataset to update its internal state based on the desired new row and after that the dataset calls back the table to do the real selection. So I'm just trying to execute an action before the new row is selected in the table.

I created a little prototype for you to have an idea of what I want. Below the prototype you'll find my questions.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JLabel selectedRow = new JLabel();

        final Table table = new Table();
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
                {
                    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                    {
                        selectedRow.setText(
                            "Selected row: " + table.getSelectedRow());
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        new DataSet(table);

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(selectedRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}

class DataSet
{
    private final Table _table;
    private int _currentIndex;

    DataSet(Table table)
    {
        _table = table;
        _table.setDataSet(this);
    }

    int getCurrentIndex()
    {
        return _currentIndex;
    }

    void moveTo(int index) throws MovementException
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > 4)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        // Let's suppose there was a problem moving to the 2nd index. Maybe
        // the data set was in edit mode and couldn't persist the changes
        // because of a validation error.
        if (index == 2)
        {
            throw new MovementException();
        }
        _currentIndex = index;
        // Notifies the table that the data was moved so that the table can
        // update its selection model based on the current index of the
        // data set.
        _table.dataMoved();
    }
}

class MovementException extends RuntimeException
{
}

class Table extends JTable
{
    private DataSet _dataSet;
    // When true signals that the data was moved in the data set, so selection
    // is allowed.
    private boolean _dataMoved;
    // Previous selected column.
    private int _oldSelectedColumn;

    Table()
    {
        super(new Model());

        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 170));

        getColumnModel().setSelectionModel(new ColumnSelectionModel());
    }

    void setDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        _dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    // Called by DataSet#moveTo.
    void dataMoved()
    {
        _dataMoved = true;
        try
        {
            int rowIndex = _dataSet.getCurrentIndex();
            // Select the new row.
            setRowSelectionInterval(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _dataMoved = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ListSelectionModel createDefaultSelectionModel()
    {
        return new RowSelectionModel();
    }

    private class ColumnSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel
    {
        @Override
        public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
        {
            // Save the old selected column to be restored in
            // RowSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval in case of an error.
            _oldSelectedColumn = getSelectedColumn();
            super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
        }
    }

    private class RowSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel
    {
        @Override
        public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
        {
            if (_dataMoved || index1 == _dataSet.getCurrentIndex())
            {
                super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    _dataSet.moveTo(index1);
                }
                catch (MovementException ex)
                {
                    // There was a problem in the data set. Restore the old
                    // selected column.
                    setColumnSelectionInterval(
                    _oldSelectedColumn, _oldSelectedColumn);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Model extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private String[] columnNames =
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", 5, false},
            {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true},
            {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", 2, false},
            {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", 20, true},
            {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", 10, false}
        };

        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c)
        {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

- Do you see any flaws in this design?
- Do I need to override more methods in the *ColumnSelectionModel* and *RowSelectionModel* classes to force the contract, or just the *setSelectionInterval* method suffices? I haven't found any flaws in this regard until now.
- It really annoys me to have the *ColumnSelectionModel* class. Its purpose is only to catch the old selected column before the new one is selected so that it can be restored in the *RowSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval* if something goes wrong. I couldn't do it only with the *RowSelectionModel* class. Is there another way?

There is another approach that doesn't use selection models. You can do this:

Comment the line `getColumnModel().setSelectionModel(new ColumnSelectionModel());` in the table constructor.

Comment the method *Table#createDefaultSelectionModel* method.

Replace the *Table#dataMoved* method by this:

```
void dataMoved()
{
    _dataMoved = true;
    try
    {
        int rowIndex = _dataSet.getCurrentIndex();
        changeSelection(rowIndex, getSelectedColumn(), false, false);
    }
    finally
    {
        _dataMoved = false;
    }
}
```

Override the *Table#changeSelection* method:

```
@Override
public void changeSelection(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
{
    if (_dataMoved)
    {
        super.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex, toggle, extend);
    }
    else
    {
        if (rowIndex != _dataSet.getCurrentIndex())
        {
            _dataSet.moveTo(rowIndex);
        }
        super.changeSelection(_dataSet.getCurrentIndex(), columnIndex, toggle, extend);
    }
}
```

But I didn't use this approach, even though it is a lot simpler than with the selection models, because the documentation of the *changeSelection* method says:

> Most changes to the selection that are the result of keyboard or mouse
>   events received by the UI are channeled through this method so that
>   the behaviour my be overriden by a subclasse.

So I interpreted

> Most changes

as not all changes, meaning that there could be some selection changes that don't pass thought this method. Am I right on this or can I trust the *changeSelection* approach?

Thank you in advance.

Marcos

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: @trashgod The problem of executing an action before the selection of a row in a JTable. The selection of the row can even be canceled if needed. In the example above, the new row in the table won't be selected if the dataset couldn't update its internal state based on the row index suggested by the table. So the row in the table is only selected in response to a dataset change, not vice-versa.

Comment: @trashgod in other words: the table should reflect the state of the dataset (its currentIndex). If the dataset can't change its currentIndex, the selected row in the table won't change as well.

Answer (score 2):

The main flaw of your approach is the hard-wired bidirectional coupling between your (navigational) model - aka: DataSet - and the view . The way out is something like a VetoableSelectionModel: then you can register the DataSet as a vetoablePropertyChangeListener to the selection model, that's loose coupling which can be configured without subclassing the table.

Some code snippets of the overall wiring:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(new Model());
VetoableListSelectionModel selectionModel = new VetoableListSelectionModel();
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
VetoableChangeListener veto = new VetoableChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
            throws PropertyVetoException {
        if (2 == (Integer) evt.getNewValue()) throw new PropertyVetoException("", evt);
    }
};
selectionModel.addVetoableChangeListener(veto);
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
    new ListSelectionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())
            {
                selectedRow.setText(
                    "Selected row: " + table.getSelectedRow());
            }
        }
    }
);
```

A skeleton selection model (full code is in [the swingx incubator](http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/kleopatra/java/org/jdesktop/beansbindingx?rev=3383) - beware: unmaintained!)

```
/**
 * Quick impl of a list selection model which respects a veto before
 * changing selection state. The veto is effect in SINGLE_SELECTION mode
 * only.
 */
public class VetoableListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {
    private VetoableChangeSupport vetoableChangeSupport;

    /**
     * Defaults to SINGLE_SELECTION mode.
     *
     */
    public VetoableListSelectionModel() {
        super();
        setSelectionMode(SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        if (isVetoable()) {
            try {
                fireVetoableChange(getMinSelectionIndex(), index0);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                // vetoed - do nothing
                return;
            }
        }
        super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
    }

    // similar for all methods that change the selection
    ...

    // methods to add/remove listeners and fire the event
    ...
}
```

Comment: Agreed. High coupling is always a bad thing. In my real application, things are a little bit cleaner, though. Glad that in your review the coupling issue was the only problem found by you.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but I think that issue is about RowInserted, please how this code can to synchronize OPs_unknow_rowIndex

Comment: @mKorbel Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Marcos _glad_ ? Strong coupling between data/controller and view is about the worst that can happen in a desktop application ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, I know, but there's a worse thing to watch out: _correctness_. If it is not correct, if there's a flaw, everything else, even low coupling, doesn't matter.

Comment: @Marcos probability to introduce incorrectness increases exponentionally with coupling :-) Anyway, good luck.